# onCancelled() seems differnet in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Just wondered what's happened with IceCream Sandwich...

I had a simple `AsyncTask` reading data from a server. When the **Disconnect** button was clicked, then `lServerTask.cancel(true);` was called which was successfully calling `onCancelled()`, setting `m_Running = false;` thus breaking out of the while loop in `protected void doInBackground(Void...params)`.

With my Galaxy Nexus, I click the disconnect button, but the task does not quit. And is still connected to the server. Does anyone have any ideas?

Many Thanks

Mark

Code FYI -

```
        // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) 
    {
        while(m_Running)
        {
            try 
            {
                lRDS.readSocket();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                lRDS.disconnectFromServer();
                publishProgress(e.toString());
                return null;
            }

            lDataBuffer = lRDS.getDataBuffer();    

            publishProgress(lDataBuffer);

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() 
    {
        m_Running = false;
        connectRDSButton.setEnabled(true);
        disconnectRDSButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

and from the UI side:

```
private class disconnectRDSButtonHandler implements View.OnClickListener
{        
    public void onClick(View v)
    {            
        editRobotData.setText("Disconnect...");
        if (lRobotDataServerTask.cancel(true) == true)
        {
            editRobotData.setText("Disconnected...");                
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: please post your update as an actual answer, then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it seems I've found the issue. I needed to check isCancelled() in the while loop of the doInBackground() method and then call the onCancelled() method from there. Not sure why I didn't see this as a problem on android 2.2 on HTC desire.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void...params)

{

while(m_Running)
{
    if (isCancelled () == true)
    {
        onCancelled();
    }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Mark

Comment: This is not the issue. You don't need to call onCancelled manually, the API will do for you (provided the main thread is still running). Check my answer for a longer explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to cancel an `AsyncTask`:

- Checking `isCancelled` inside your `doInBackground` method to try to terminate as soon as possible.
- Calling `cancel(true)`, then `AsyncTask`'s background thread will be interrupted. For this to work, you'll need to strategically place `Thread.sleep` calls in your `doInBackground` method, and when you catch the `InterruptedException`, you return.

Of these two approaches, the latter is the most unreliable by far, since any call to a method catching an `InterruptedException` other than yours will screw the cancellation. For instance, if you call a method such as `SystemClock.sleep` that swallows the exception, you'll never hit your catch clause.

In both cases, long operations in between `isCancelled` checks or `Thread.sleep` calls will run to completion.

Now about your question, you were using the second approach, but there were not any `Thread.sleep` call, so it wont work unless some of the methods you are calling catched the Interrupted exception and throwed the IOException. Probably changes in implementation from a version to another make the difference.